# How to change the text position

Tags: html, css, django

I am new in programing industry especially in css/html stuff.
Does someone of you know how to change the position of text or how to make another box/table with all that information beside the card with picture of actor?

Do I have to make new div or something?
Add something to css?

[image]

My CSS:

```css
body {
  background: url('/static/images/backkk.jpg');
}

.navbar-inverse {
  background-color: #222;
  border-color: #080808;
}

.card{
  display: inline-table ;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  grid-template-columns: 300px;
  grid-template-rows: 330px 300px 40px;
  grid-template-areas: "image" "text" "stats";
  border-radius: 7px;
  background: url('/static/images/back.jpg');
  box-shadow: 7px 7px 7px rgba(252, 135, 2, 0.9);
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  border:3px solid rgb(255, 189, 7);
}

/*height card*/
.card-text        
{
  grid-area: text;
  margin: 25px;
}

/*  pilot*/
.card-text p {
  color: rgb(16, 207, 144);
  font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
  font-size:17px;
  font-weight: 300;
  border:"3px solid #73AD21";
  text-align: center
}

.card-text h2 {
  margin-top:20px;
  font-size:23px;
}

/* lenght of card*/
.card {
  transition: 0.5s ease;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top:-200px;
  right: -30%;
  width: 300px;
  height: 35rem;
}
```

And my HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="card" >
        <div class="card-image">
          <img src="{{ actor.picture }}" alt="No poster in datebase"    width="289" height="345">
        </div>
    <div class="card-text">
      <h2>
        <a href="/actors/actor_detail/{{actor.id }}">{{ actor.name }}</a>  
      </h2>
    </div>
    <div class="card-text"> 
        <p>Age: {{ actor.age}} </p>
        <p>Net-worth: {{actor.net_worth}}</p>
        <p>Date-of-birth: {{actor.date_of_birth}}</p>
        <p>Children: {{actor.children}}</p>
        <p>Marital-status: {{actor.marital_status}}</p>  
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need create another `div` to put the information of the actor inside. To change the position of the text after, you need to create a style of the text in CSS, obviously. To do this, use the attributes: `position:relative; top:0px; left:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px;` (choose the number of pixels that you prefer).

I'm not sure to understand your doubt, but my understanding is that you want to put the same information that are below the actor on the right side... am I right?

This box with red border that are in description image that you show need be a new `div`, and the information inside, need be text elements or another element that you can put the information.